# Locating a user by alternate email address in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I currently use

```
(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $EmailAddress).ObjectID.Guid
```

to lookup a user by their PrincipalName in Azure AD and return their guid.  However, there are times when a user has changed email addresses due to a name change and the address I have been given is not their PrincipalName but a secondary email address.

Is there a way to locate a user based upon an alternate email address?  Perhaps a fuzzy search?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of 'user' accounts in your tenant, it could take a little while for each user account to be returned.  Please see following:

```
Get-MsolUser -all | Where{$_.ProxyAddresses -like "smtp:<EMAIL ADDRESS>"}
(Get-MsolUser -all | Where{$_.ProxyAddresses -like "smtp:<EMAIL ADDRESS>"}).ObjectId.Guid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow PowerShell scripts to filter user with one Alternate Email Address:

```
Get-MsolUser | Where-Object{$_.AlternateEmailAddresses -contains "<the email ddress>"}


(Get-MsolUser | Where-Object{$_.AlternateEmailAddresses -contains "<the email dress>"}).ObjectId.Guid
```

Here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: This solution looks very elegant but it throws an error that -All should be used.  When I add -All it yields no results.  I suspect the problem is how alternate addresses are stored in my AAD.

Comment: Hi @Notamachine , It works in my test lab. Can you tell me the details about the error ?

Comment: @wayne-yang-msft  There is no error when I use the -All switch.  It simply doesn't return a value.  If I omit the -All switch then I receive this error "WARNING: More results are available. Please specify one of the All or MaxResults parameters."